# What would be a better way to make a calendar than using labels?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, calendar, label

I've created my own winforms month-view calendar in VB.net.

To do it I've used a table layout panel, with 42 separate cells. In each of the cells is a label called `lblDay1`, `lblDay2`, etc.

When I load the page, the labels are all written to with the correct numbers for that month.

```
 Dim daysInMonthCnt As Integer =31 'Assume 31 days for now
 Dim firstDay As Integer = Weekday("1/" & Now.month & "/" & Now.year) 'Get weekday for 1st of month
 For dayCount As Integer = firstDay To daysInMonthCnt
    Dim lbl As Label
    lbl = CType(pnlMonthBody.Controls("lblDay" & dayCount), Label)
    lbl.Text = dayCount 'Write to label
 Next dayCount
```

Unfortunately, that turns out to be incredibly slow to load. Can anyone please suggest a faster method.

Comment: Doesn't VB.NET have a `MonthCalendarControl`?  Or perhaps, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)?

Comment: Firstly, I do agree with the proposal above. But in case that you want to do it yourself anyway (for fun or for work or whatever), my question is: when/how many times are you calling this code to create the labels?

Comment: `What would be a better way to make a calendar than using labels?` - Use non-deprecated .Net Windows UI technology (WPF) and use an `ItemsControl`, or probably a `ListBox`.

Comment: @Brian Yes, there is a built-in month calendar. But suffice to say, it doesn't quite do what I want. So I'm building my own.

Comment: @varocarbas It gets called whenever you change the month. But it's not creating the labels. It's just writing to labels that are already there. Would creating them be quicker?

Comment: No, creating them every time would certainly be slower. You are saying that just writing the values to 42 labels is too slow? It should be a really quick process; perhaps the problem is the container you are using and the time associated to refresh labels every time. Let me write an answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: @varocarbas Just tried creating the labels dynamically, and can confirm that-yes- it's even slower. I think your diagnosis is probably correct- I just can't figure out another way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried what I have proposed in my answer? Just as a quick test: put all the labels in a simple panel, include a button and a timer. Make the button to change the contents of the labels (for this test, just for 2 months) and to trigger a simplistic transition with the timer. Putting all this together would take you less than 30 mins and would let you get an idea of the kind of performance which can be delivered.

Comment: @varocarbas The labels load really fast when I put them in a `panel`, instead of a `tableLayoutPanel`. What do you mean by "simplistic transition"?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just writing values to a so small number of labels is a really fast process. The problems you are experiencing have to do most likely with the VB.NET "problems" while refreshing the contents of GUI controls; the best way to fix this is looking into multithreading, as suggested by FraserOfSmeg.

As far as I think that this is a pretty simplistic GUI with a low number of controls and a not too demanding algorithm (big amount of/long loops is the prime cause of GUI-refreshing problems), you might get an acceptable performance even without relying on multithreading. In your situation, I would do the following:

1. A container (the `TableLayoutPanel` you are using or something
   simpler, like a `Panel`) including all the labels at the start. In
   case of not getting too messy (what does not seem to be the case,
   with just 42 labels) I would include them in the "design view"
   (rather than at run time).
2. A function populating all the labels depending upon the given month.
3. A "transition effect" for
   the container called every time the user selects a different month.
   You can accomplish this quite easily with a `Timer` relocating the
   container (e.g., when the button is clicked the container's position
   is set outside the form and then comes back gradually (20 points per
   10ms -> made-up numbers) until being back to its original position).
4. Synchronising the two points above: the values of the labels
   will start changing when the transition starts; in this way the user
   will not notice anything (just a nice-appealing transition
   month to month).

This GUI should deliver the kind of performance you are after. If not, you should improve its performance by relying on additional means (e.g., the proposed multi-threading).

SAMPLE CODE TO ILLUSTRATE POINT 3

Add a panel (`Panel1`), a button (`Button1`) and a timer (`Timer1`) to a new form and the code below.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim curX, origX, timerInterval, XIncrease As Integer
    Dim moving As Boolean
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If (curX >= origX) Then
            If (moving) Then
                curX = Panel1.Location.X
                moving = False
                Timer1.Stop()
            Else
                curX = 0 'getting it out of the screen
                moving = True
            End If
        Else
            curX = curX + XIncrease
        End If
        Panel1.Location = New Point(curX, Panel1.Location.Y)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        XIncrease = 100
        timerInterval = 100
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.Maroon
        origX = Panel1.Location.X
        curX = origX
        With Timer1
            .Enabled = False
            .Interval = timerInterval
        End With

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is very simplistic, but shows the idea clearly: when you click the button the panel moves in X; by affecting the `timerInterval` and `XIncrease` values you can get a nice-looking transition (there are lots of options, bear in mind that if you set `curX` to minus the width of the panel, rather than to zero, it goes completely outside the form).

Comment: Thanks. I don't really follow point 3. Can you write some code to illustrate what you mean.

Comment: I've run the example you've given. But I don't really see the point of the transition effect. Why not just leave the labels in their current positions?

Comment: @Urbycoz The point is showing a transition when changing from month to month. Bear in mind that the one in my code is very slow, you can do it faster (1 ms instead of 100 ms or 1000 points in X instead 100). The labels will be in the panel every time, but when you change the month it might look better if the panel moves (even very quickly) and this might hide eventual delays in the refreshing of label values. Actually this is done in the in-built MonthCalendar (a better version). This was just a suggestion of the kind of functionalities I would include, you don't need to include everything.

Comment: Ah I see. You were further ahead than me. I'm just catching up now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're purely interested in speeding up your code I'd suggest running the loading code on multiple threads simultaneously. This may be overkill depending on your application needs but it's a good way to code. As a side note so the program looks a little more slick for the end user I'd suggest always running time consuming processes such as this on a separate thread(s).

For info on multithreading have a look at this page:[Mutlithreading tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4358/Introduction-to-making-multithreaded-VB-NET-Apps)